# Distributions related to the normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be i.i.d $N(0,1)$ random variables. Let $\overline{X_k}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_i$, $\overline{X_{n-k}}=\frac{1}{n-k}\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}X_i.$
>
> What is the distribution of $\frac{1}{2}(\overline{X_k}+\overline{X_{n-k}})$?

My attempt:

$\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_i\sim N(0,k)$

$\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}X_i\sim N(0,n-k-1)$

$\overline{X_k}\sim N(0,\frac{1}{k})$

$\overline{X_{n-k}}\sim N(0,\frac{n-k-1}{(n-k)^{2}})=N(0,\frac{1}{n-k}-\frac{1}{(n-k)^2})$

$(\overline{X_k}+\overline{X_{n-k}})\sim N(0,\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k}-\frac{1}{(n-k)^2})=N(0,\frac{n}{k(n-k)}-\frac{1}{(n-k)^2})=N(0,\frac{n(n-k)-k}{k(n-k)^2}) $

$\frac{1}{2}(\overline{X_k}+\overline{X_{n-k}})\sim N(0,\frac{n}{k(n-k)}-\frac{1}{(n-k)^2})=N(0,\frac{n(n-k)-k}{4k(n-k)^2}) $

Is this correct? Is it possible to express the answer in terms of another distribution (gamma, t, F, $\chi^2$, etc.)?

Comment: There's ambiguity of your notation:  $\overline{X_{1}}=X_{1}$ or $X_{n}$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\frac{X_{1}+\ldots+X_{k}}{k} \sim N \left( 0,\frac{1}{k} \right)$$

and

$$\frac{X_{k+1}+\ldots+X_{n}}{n-k} \sim N \left( 0,\frac{1}{n-k} \right)$$

So

$$\frac{X_{1}+\ldots+X_{k}}{k}+\frac{X_{k+1}+\ldots+X_{n}}{n-k}
\sim N \left( 0,\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k} \right)$$

> $$\frac{1}{2} \left(
>  \frac{X_{1}+\ldots+X_{k}}{k}+\frac{X_{k+1}+\ldots+X_{n}}{n-k} \right)
> \sim N \left( 0,\frac{n}{4k(n-k)} \right)$$

In particular when $n=2k$,

$$\frac{1}{2} \left(
 \frac{X_{1}+\ldots+X_{k}}{k}+\frac{X_{k+1}+\ldots+X_{n}}{n-k} \right) \sim N \left( 0,\frac{1}{2k} \right)$$

that is

$$\frac{X_{1}+\ldots+X_{n}}{n} \sim N \left( 0,\frac{1}{n} \right)$$